# Adding labels iteratively to Tkinter form

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to iteratively add fields to a `Tkinter` form by looping through a list. The form generates with no errors, but the labels are not present. What is going on here?

```
from Tkinter import *
class User_Input:

def __init__(self, parent):
    fields = ['Text Box 1', 'Text Box 2', 'Text Box 3']
    GUIFrame =Frame(parent, width=300, height=200)
    GUIFrame.pack(expand=False, anchor=CENTER)
    field_index = 10
    for field in fields:
        self.field = Entry() #possibly make this Entry(GUIFrame)
        self.field.place(x=65, y = field_index)
        field_index += 25

    field_index = 10
    for field in fields:
        self.field = Label()
        self.field.place(x=0, y = field_index)
        field_index += 25

    self.Button2 = Button(parent, text='Done', command= parent.quit)
    self.Button2.place(x=150, y=field_index)

root = Tk()
MainFrame =User_Input(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

For one thing you overwrite your self.field in the loop. Only the last Entry will not be garbage collected. Add an list attribute self.fields and append each Entry to it instead. And give your entries a parent as well.

Comment: I agree that only the final Entry will be an attribute of the instance, but I believe all the widgets will escape garbage collection because their parent widget keeps a reference to them as long as it's alive.

Comment: @Kevin: I fail to see where the Entries get a parent. They're orphans as far as I can see.

Comment: IIRC, if you don't explicitly supply a parent when you create a non-toplevel widget, it automatically adds itself to the last `Tk` instance the user created. However, I consider this behavior a little spooky, so I agree that OP should give the entries a parent.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `text` attribute of `Entry` doesn't actually do anything. Try explicitly inserting the string into the widget.

```
    for field in fields:
        self.field = Entry() #possibly make this Entry(GUIFrame)
        self.field.insert(END, field)
        self.field.place(x=65, y = field_index)
        field_index += 25
```

Now your entries will have default values of "Text Box 1" and "Text Box 2" respectively.

---

If you want the text to be *outside* of the entry, I don't think there's any way to do that without explicitly creating a Label and putting it next to the entry. But you can at least reduce your bookkeeping by creating a custom class that creates both widgets for you.

```
from Tkinter import *

class LabeledEntry(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kargs):
        text = kargs.pop("text")
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.label = Label(self, text=text)
        self.label.grid(column=0,row=0)
        self.entry = Entry(self, *args, **kargs)
        self.entry.grid(column=1,row=0)

class User_Input:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        fields = ['Text Box 1', 'Text Box 2']
        GUIFrame =Frame(parent, width=300, height=200)
        GUIFrame.pack(expand=False, anchor=CENTER)
        field_index = 10
        for field in fields:
            self.field = LabeledEntry(GUIFrame, text=field)
            self.field.place(x=65, y = field_index)
            field_index += 25
        self.Button2 = Button(parent, text='exit', command= parent.quit)
        self.Button2.place(x=160, y=60)

root = Tk()
MainFrame =User_Input(root)
root.mainloop()
```

(Although this somewhat complicates attribute/method access on the entry, since now you need to do e.g. `self.field.entry.insert(...)` instead of `self.field.insert(...)`. But you could always define a custom `insert` method in `LabeledEntry` that passes along its arguments to `self.entry.insert`, if you were feeling inclined.)

---

Update in response to question edit: or just specify the `text` attribute of your Labels.

```
from Tkinter import *
class User_Input:

    def __init__(self, parent):
        fields = ['Text Box 1', 'Text Box 2', 'Text Box 3']
        GUIFrame =Frame(parent, width=300, height=200)
        GUIFrame.pack(expand=False, anchor=CENTER)
        field_index = 10
        for field in fields:
            self.field = Entry() #possibly make this Entry(GUIFrame)
            self.field.place(x=65, y = field_index)
            field_index += 25

        field_index = 10
        for field in fields:
            self.field = Label(text=field)
            self.field.place(x=0, y = field_index)
            field_index += 25

        self.Button2 = Button(parent, text='Done', command= parent.quit)
        self.Button2.place(x=150, y=field_index)

root = Tk()
MainFrame =User_Input(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I actually want it to be a label outside of the text box (to the left)

Comment: Thanks that looks good. I updated my original question to reflect the separate labels

Comment: Is there a way to line up the entry boxes?

Comment: The labels are lined up, but the entry box starts at the end of the label for me. If you change the labels to be text of different lengths they don't line up.

Comment: (assuming we're talking about my third code sample) The entries are still aligned, but the longer label is lying on top of its accompanying Entry and making it appear shorter. The quick fix is to increase the x-coordinate of each Entry. The long fix is to not use `place` at all, instead using the grid geometry manager to place each of your widgets in a particular row and column.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81904/discussion-between-user2242044-and-kevin).